# python loop till depth is not known django

Tags: python, django

I have a Custom User model in django where a user1 reports to another user2 in a hierarchy. This user will report to another user3 and so on until the top level user4 does not report to anyone. So until this condition is met, all the tasks assigned at the lowest  should be assigned to that user1, while all the tasks assigned above him, should be available at user2 and so on. So user4 should be able to see all task status for users below him i.e user1,2,3. The depth of this hierarchy is not known, until the user does not report to anybody else. Is there a  iterative function to determine the last user4 level which can be written in a simple way in python using lambda or some recursive looping etc? Sample code tried:

Resolved as:
In the model admin queryset:

```
rep_users = []
reporting_custom_users = CustomUser.objects.filter(
    report_to=request.user.customuser.pk)

if reporting_custom_users:
    rep_users = get_all_users(self,request,reporting_custom_users)
else:
    rep_users = [request.user]

qs = Task.objects.filter(Q(assigned_to__in=rep_users)|
                         Q(requestor__in=rep_users))

return qs
```

The recursive function, that I tried:

```
sub_users = []
def get_all_users(self,request,reporting_custom_users):
    rep_users = []
    for n in reporting_custom_users:
        sub_users.append(n)
        while True:
            get_all_users(self,request,CustomUser.objects.filter(
                    report_to=n))
            if n.report_to is None:
                rep_users.append(n)
            break
rep_users += sub_users
rep_users.append(request.user.customuser)

reporting_users = []
for m in list(set(rep_users)):
    reporting_users.append(User.objects.get(id=m.muser.pk))

return reporting_users
```

The only care to be taken is that if user1 reporting to user2, same user2 is not reporting to user1. This can be done in form validation.

Comment: Have you tried to code anything? We don't even know what your custom user model looks like (does it have a `hierarchy` attribute?), but there are probably many ways to implement this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try flattening it.

```
def flatten(di):
    stack = [di]
    while stack:
        e = stack[-1]
        for k, v in e.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                stack.append(v)
            else:
                yield k, v
        stack.remove(e)
```

Then, you can do something like:

```
for k, v in flatten(mycomplexdict):
    process(k, v)
```